# How to Check If QueryString has no parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing one issue in Querystring when I don't have any parameters.Please find the below example. I have a below URL

**1 Scenario**

```
URL ---http://localhost/Employee/Emp/empmanagement.aspx
```

and I'm checking one condition and it is throwing error Request is not available

```
if(Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("employeeData"))
```

**2 Scenario**

```
URL ---http://localhost/Employee/Emp/empmanagement.aspx?empData=employeeData
```

and it is working fine below

```
if(Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("employeeData"))
```

Thanks Guys everyone's answer is correct the issue was because of my context.Qerystring was not returing.So,i declared in my aspx page and it is working fine for me.

ASPX Code

```
 <cw:QueryString runat="server" ID="_empValue"  Required="False" />
```

Code Behind Code

```
if(_empValue.Value != null && _empValue.Value.Contains("employeeData")
```

Comment: Have you ever check it's `Count` property like `Request.QueryString.Count > 0`?

Comment: Hi Soner,Actually in above first scenario there are no parameters so even Request is not coming.it is throwing error Request is not available in this context

Comment: Where do you write those lines exactly? Which file?

Comment: @SonerGönül do you think `.ToString()` is the culprit in the first line?

Comment: @शेखर It can be. Since `QueryString` returns `NameValueCollection`, calling `ToString` calls `object.ToString` and this _might_ behave differently for it. I don't know honestly. I do not have a compiler right now.

Comment: Hi Guys,Its quite weird but sometimes same code is working fine but sometimes even request is not present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough

```
if(Request != null && Request.QueryString["employeeData"] != null)
{
}
```

OR

```
if (Request != null && Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
{
}
```

OR

```
if (Request != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["employeeData"]))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString` is nothing but a `NameValueCollection` i.e. one of collection. So like other collections it also has `Count` property. So you can check

```
Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
{

}
```

or you can try

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Any(i => i == "query"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Request!=null && Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
{
     if(Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("employeeData"))
     {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, everyone's answer is correct the issue was because of my context query string was not returning sometimes.

So, I declared in my aspx page and it is working fine for me.

ASPX markup:

```
<cw:QueryString runat="server" ID="_empValue"  Required="False" />
```

Code-behind:

```
if(_empValue.Value != null && _empValue.Value.Contains("employeeData")
```